# send post data on button click which is not the submit button of a form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form as show by the following code in HTML 5.

```
<form name='removeTen' method='POST' action='notRemove.php'>
<table id='tender'>
<thead>
<tr><th></th>
<th><input id='selectAll' type='checkbox'></th>
<th>Notice Title</th>
<th>Edit </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ten[]" value="1"</td>
<td>somedata1</td>
<td><input type = 'button' value = 'Edit' name ='1' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ten[]" value="2"</td>
<td>somedata1</td>
<td><input type = 'button' value = 'Edit' name ='2' ></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table><p><input type=reset value='Reset'>
<input type=submit value='Submit'></p>
</form>
```

Now I want to redirect to another page `notEdit.php` with post data that is contained in the name of the button when I click the buttons `Edit`. I also want to keep the functionality of the form using the `submit` button. I have added the following Javascript code:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("edit");
for(var i = 0, count = buttons.length; i<count; i++){
    buttons[i].attachEvent("click", submit);
}
```

Now in the `submit` function I can add `window.location` to redirect to another page. But How can I attach the post data?

Comment: with or without ajax?

Comment: why not set form action to 'notEdit.php'? that will automatically post your data to notEdit.php page.

Comment: @Vandervals without ajax.

Comment: Maybe you can switch the action path just before submiting it and after you don't need it eny more for your usability purposes

Comment: @gp. the form action is to delete the elements that are selected using the checkboxes in the table. While clicking the button in the table would result to editing the selected Item.

Comment: you can have another form with a hidden input and action='notEdit.php'. On click of a button set the appropriate value and call submit on that form. This will do a POST of relevant data to notEdit.php.

Comment: @gp. could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in click handler function, get the row number from the clicked button's name.
set this to an input field of another form and trigger submit on that form.

```
function submit(e){
    //get the clicked button's "name" attribute value.
    var row_no = e.currentTarget.name;
    alert(row_no);

    //set the value to the edit form
    var row_no_element = document.querySelector("input[name=row_no]");
    row_no_element.value = row_no;

    //submit the edit form. uncomment this line to submit.
    //document.getElementById("editForm").submit();
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
for(var i = 0, count = buttons.length; i<count; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", submit);
}
```

The new form to be submitted for edit:

```
<form id="editForm" action='notEdit.php' method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="row_no" />
</form>
```

JSFiddle (with html correction): http://jsfiddle.net/xfLa3tnb/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name='actionForm' method='POST' action='actionEditOrRemove.php'>
```

Use hidden input to pass action (Edit or Remove).

Comment: I do not want to change the action of the form as `notRemove.php` deletes the selected items from the database while `notEdit.php` edits the individual items in a new form.

Comment: I have updated the answer to satisfy the requirement. Is it something you considering?

Comment: do you mean to say that I pass the post to a new php file `actionEditOrRemov.php`? But how do I identify which row button was clicked to open the edit window?

Comment: Same as when you post to notRemove.php. Essentially clicking on the submit button will select action and submit the form, so in PHP code you act on what needed to be done, Edit or Remove based on action input on the form submitted.